# PhpStorm server using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpstorm

When developing a project using the IDE PhpStorm Codeigniter have the problem that if I do not generate a server does not send me the url of the controller to use the debug port , and if I think it also gives me a server to access failures . I do not know which is the optimal setting .

`http://localhost:63342/U5AP1E2Alex/index.php`
(U5AP1E2Alex  is the project's folder) It`s OK

`http://localhost:63342/U5AP1E2Alex/index.php/tienda/index` (Function index in controller Tienda) It's KO - 404 Not Found

If I build a Deployment Server I have problems too.. What's better configuration??

Comment: Use proper Apache/nginx/etc web server instead of PhpStrom's own simple built in web server (which you are using right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CodeIgniter 3v + Common checks 404 error.

http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

1: Check file name has first letter upper case:

**Tienda.php**

2: Check class name has first letter upper case:

```
<?php

class Tienda extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {

    }
}
```

Make sure  your config base url is not empty

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:63342/U5AP1E2Alex/';
```

If your url `http://localhost:63342/U5AP1E2Alex/index.php/tienda/` <strike>index</strike> then that should go direct to index function no need to have the function index at end of url

You may need to configure some routes http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

```
$route['tienda'] = 'tienda/index';
```

Or if in sub folder i.e controllers > some_folder > Tienda.php

```
$route['tienda'] = 'some_folder/tienda/index';
```

**UPDATE:**

If you do not need index.php in url then I suggest you remove it by making this blank like below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And adding a htaccess file in your main directory. [Some htaccess Examples](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

Comment: Thanks , I managed to work with your instructions . The only failure now is that if I try to access the index.php by  localhost / index.php (or directly the link brownser of PhpStorm ), the address to which I refer is localhost / xampp.

Comment: @JulenMLejarza If you do not want index.php in url I have updated the question. Also don't for get to up vote or accept answers if help full.